# Can I test my In App Purchase in the sandbox when the App is in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, sandbox, in-app-purchase

My app is already in the App Store but there seems to be a bug with the In App Purchase. I want to debug it but I cannot get into the sandbox environment with my iPhone and XCode. Is there anything special I have to do to work in the sandbox again? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using your dev version of the app, not the one that's in the App Store, right?

Assuming you are, checkout the following checklist:

1. Make sure that you are using a QA product ID - the one you defined in iTunes Connect for testing purposes. If don't have a product ID that you use for QA, I suggest you create one (or several if you have multiple in-app purchase products).
2. Verify that you are logged in on the iPhone as the user that you have created for the purpose of in-app purchase QA. You can change your iTunes user on the device from the Settings application.
3. As you probably know, you can't test the full in-app purchase cycle in the Simulator and you must do that on a real device.

I hope this helps,

Ori

Comment: Yes I did all that already. It worked before. But after submitting it to the store its not in the sandbox anymore.